# Cannot read properties of 'null' (reading appendChild)

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? This works for all the other elements on the page but not this one, which is the parent to all of them.

```js
let addButton = document.querySelector('.add-note');
addButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  //prevent refresh
  event.preventDefault();
  //note input value
  let noteInput = document.querySelector(".note-input");
  //create note container
  let noteList = document.querySelector(".notes");
  //create note
  let note = document.createElement("li");
  note.classList.add("note");
  noteList.appendChild(note);
});
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
</div>
<br>
<form>
  <div class="add-note">
    <input class="note-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter to-do item here"></input>
    <button class="add" type="submit">+</button>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<ul className="notes" id="notes"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a React project? `className` is only available when using React.

```
<ul className="notes" id="notes"></ul>
```

change to

```
<ul class="notes" id="notes"></ul>
```

Comment: oops forgot to change that, must've missed it. it was a react project, I'm in the process of changing it back to a vanilla javascript project.

Answer (score 0):

Your question i a tad unclear, but i think part of it is that you added the event listener to the div instead of the submit button. Change the class in your query selector to ".add" instead of ".add-note".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just meant the console was throwing the error in the title and I wanted to know why :)